# What do you call the activity of holding {publicity/protest/facts} signs

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

What's the word for a place and/or activity where a small number of people stand in the streets with information boards in their hands and inform the passersby people about something (which the information boards are about)?

Comment: I think there are probably different words depening on what the 'something' is. e.g. if it's some kind of marketing activity it might be a 'promotion', but if it's more about drawing attention to a political issue it could be a 'campaign' perhaps an 'awareness-raising' campaign.

Comment: And if it was a charity, it could be "fundraising" (or, in the UK, "chugging", a portmanteau of "charity" and "mugging").

Comment: something refers to the meaning of the day (like a holiday)

Comment: This seems (from your comments) to be about a very specific activity so you need to clarify what you are asking about, instead of this very general question.

Answer (score 1):

If they're trying to spread information about their religion they could be **evangelising**. If they're trying to bring awareness to an issue (likely political) this cold be a **rally**. If they're unhappy with an event or ruling this might be a **protest**.

Comment: none of that :) they're informing people (mainly tourists) about the meaning of the day (a holiday)

Comment: @user3132457 - you are saying that there are people on the streets who inform other people about the meaning  of a holiday, like Christmas or Easter? Where did you see this?

Comment: @user3132457 What holiday and what meaning?

Comment: A national holiday, something like celebrating the victory of revolution.

Comment: @user3132457 so you want an answer about the **type** of information offered? "campaign" or "public awareness" might do the trick. *Evangelising* is a good answer. But you need to edit your question and make it clearer.